# give parameters in sql expression in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, collation

I want to use collation in a query in NHibernate and apparently the only way to do that (at least from what I found) is through adding an sql expression ([Can I customize collation of query results in nHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201583/can-i-customize-collation-of-query-results-in-nhibernate))

So I have something like

```
c.Add(Expression.Sql("Title COLLATE Divehi_90_BIN2 LIKE ?", 
                     title, 
                     NHibernateUtil.String))
```

However this matches the exact string and I want to use % on both sides.

`Title COLLATE Divehi_90_BIN2 LIKE %?%` gives me an error,

but padding it on the title: `"%" + title + "%"` works.

My question is - Is there a way to properly give parameters in Expression.Sql because using the % on both sides looks like a security flaw - that I am inviting query injection.

PS. I can't change the collation of the column at the database level because the column contains data that are of two languages.

Comment: What SQL is generated by NHibernate for the `Title COLLATE Divehi_90_BIN2 LIKE %?%` attempt?

Comment: > [SQL: SELECT top 5 this_.Title as Title11_1_, this_.Preface as Preface11_1_, this_.Body as Body11_1_, this_.IsPublished as IsPublis5_11_1_ FROM Books WHERE Title COLLATE Divehi_90_BIN2 LIKE %@p0% and this_.IsPublished = @p1]
Positional parameters:  #0>women #1>True

Comment: I get an Nhibernate.ADO exception - could not execute query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `%@p0%` is not a quoted string, i.e. `'%@p0%'`.

From the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#querycriteria-narrowing) it seems this is the recommended form.

```
Expression.Sql("Title COLLATE Divehi_90_BIN2 LIKE ?", 
               String.Format("%{0}%", title),
               NHibernateUtil.String)
```

Please note that the string `String.Format("%{0}%", title)` will be passed in as a parameter so you are not inviting sql injection attacks by this approach.