# NHibernate extend restiction

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need extend Like restriction to support accent insensitive, but I don't know where tinkering. Anyone know how I do this? I can't change collate in all customer databases and I'm using criteria and can't change this because I create a infrastructure that wrap criteria in my domain.

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1

You can do this with an SQL expression, i.e.

```
Expression.Sql(
      "your_field COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI LIKE ? COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI", 
      String.Format("%{0}%", your_field),
      NHibernateUtil.String)
```

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183167/give-parameters-in-sql-expression-in-nhibernate/16193190#16193190) to a similar question for further details.
 Also please see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-e-e-e-and-e-in-sql-ser) for details on the correct SQL format.

This, of course, is limited to a specific DBMS, in the example case SQL Server.

### Approach 2

Another approach is to sub-class the NHibernate dialect for each DBMS the system will be used with, and add a custom function to each of these custom dialects. For example,

```
public class CustomMsSqlDialect : MsSql2005Dialect
{
  public CustomMsSqlDialect()
  {
      RegisterFunction("accentinsensitivelike",
        new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.String,
            "?1 COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI like ?2 collate Latin1_general_CI_AI"));
  }
}
```

Then to call it use something like

```
var user = session.CreateQuery("from User u 
                                where accentinsensitivelike(u.name, :name)")
                  .SetParameter("name", name)
                  .UniqueResult<User>();
```

This has the advantage of working across multiple DBMS but is quite a bit more work than the first approach.

For further details please the following

http://blog.schuager.com/2009/06/case-sensitive-queries-in-nhibernate.html

[Can I customize collation of query results in nHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201583/can-i-customize-collation-of-query-results-in-nhibernate)

Hope this helps.

Comment: My app can run in different databases, so I can't use this.

Comment: @DiegoDias I have updated my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: I preferred to create a custom criteria to resolve my problem. I check the dialect and then I create a custom query expression.

Comment: @DiegoDias it would be good if you add an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem creating a custom criterion where I check dialect to identify what's the RDBMS that NHibernate are using, and then I create custom expression to it.

My code is here: [source code](https://gist.github.com/diegodfsd/5516257)